How to show that the parametrization fills up the variety over a field
This is assignment 3.3-9 from Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms by Cox, Little, O'Shea.
We are given the Whitney umbrella surface with parametrization
$$
x=u\cdot v, y=v, z=u^2
$$
Firstly we are asked to find the equation of the smallest variety containing the Whitney umbrella which is not difficult to find and it is $x^2-y^2z=0$. The next question is
Show that the parametrization fills up the variety over $\mathbb{C}$ but not over $\mathbb{R}$. Over $\mathbb{R}$, exactly what points are omitted?
My questions are:

What does it mean for a parametrization to fill up a variety over a field?
How to show that a parametrization fills up a variety over a field?
Is it correct that the points omitted over $\mathbb{R}$ are $\{(uv, v, u^2) : u^2 < 0, u,v \in \mathbb{C} \}$?


A parametrization fills up a variety over a field $k$ if the map
$$k^2\to W(k):=\{(x,y,z)\in k^3:x^2=y^2z\}:(u,v)\mapsto (uv,v,u^2)$$
is surjective.
In fact over any field $k$, the map surjects on to $\{(x,y,z)\in W(k):y\ne0\}$, since one can simply pick $(u,v)=(x/y,y)$. So the only concern is when $y=0$, when $x=0$ and $z$ is arbitrary.
So we are wondering when $(0,0,z)\in W(k)$ can be written as $(0,0,z)=(uv,v,u^2)$ for some $u,v\in k$. But we see $v=0$, hence we are simply asking for a $u\in k$ such that $u^2=z$. When $k=\mathbb C$ we can always find such a $u$ but not always over $\mathbb R$. Very explicitly, $(0,0,-1)\in W(\mathbb R)$ is not in the image of the parametrization.
